# Downloading a .zip from GitHub removes newlines from text files

Tags: git, github

I have a small project on GitHub. The project includes a Readme.txt. Everything works fine in the repository and the newlines are still there, but when a user downloads the .zip file from the repo, the newlines disappear.

Example:

> This is a line.
>   This is another line.
>   `This is an indented line.`
>
> This line is far below.

becomes:

> This is a line.This is another line. This is an intended line.This
>   line is far below.

This behavior makes the Readme.txt pretty hard to read, especially if it has a lot of indentation.

Is there a way to fix this? Preferably other than changing the file type.

And for clarification, I'm aiming to do this without Git, with the "Download ZIP" button in the GitHub page.

Comment: Fyi, the newlines aren't being removed. They are still there, notepad just doesn't know how to display them. Try opening the downloaded files with Notepad++ or in an IDE. Otherwise, you'll have to change the committed file to use Windows-style line endings.

Comment: @Ajedi True there, but as I can't assume that everyone that is going to use this project has Notepad++, and not to even mention an IDE, it seems that it's better for me to go with changing the line endings.

Comment: Good point. I just wanted to make it clear that it was Notepad, not GitHub, that was making the newlines disappear.

Comment: @Ajedi Yeah, I wasn't too clear with the original question. Everything would be a lot easier if everyone would just use Notepad++ or at least something better than the default Notepad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [nulltoken explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17351084/758345), this is caused by the fact that GitHub runs `git archive` on a linux machine that will default to linux line endings. You can change this by explicitly setting line endings for the files in your repo. To achieve this, create a `.gitattributes` file with the following content in the root of your repo and commit it.

```
*.txt eol=crlf
```

All GitHub created zips of revisions that contain that file will now have `CRLF` line endings in all `.txt` files. You can expand that to all files by using `*` instead of `*.txt`, but I would advice against that because it will make linux users sad.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 3):

Internally, the *"Download Zip"* feature from GitHub leverages `git archive`.

`git archive` actually performs a checkout of the pointed at commit, streaming the content to the tar or zip archiver.

The way the line endings are being dealt with, during the checkout process, eventually depends on the platform the command is being run on.

As GitHub servers are Linux based, the selected line ending for text files will be the Linux native one (i.e. LF).

So there's (currently) no way to interfere with this and text files inside your zip/tar downloads will be LF terminated.

However you may still

- Use a tool like **[Unix2Dos](http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html)** to batch convert your text files
- Send a mail to support@github.com and request for a change to their UI so that one could potentially select the expected line endings

Comment: All right, if that's the case I think I'll go with the trouble of either using Unix2Dos or writing a short Python script to do the job. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Actually adding a `.gitattributes` with content `* eol=crlf` should fix that problem. Or if you just want all txt files to be affected: `*.txt eol=crlf`.

Comment: @Chronial For this to works, the .gitattributes file should be part of the repo before it's downloaded, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Chronial I shall try that one then. I have been trying to include a .gitattributes to the project before but for some reason that did nothing good. I'll just try again.

Comment: @nulltoken: yes it should be. But since OP has control over the repo, he can just add it. NotTheOP: try – and if it doesn’t work, give us a link to your repo (if possible).

Comment: @Chronial I finally got it to work, and as you said, the .gitattributes solved it. It just took me a few moments to figure out where I should be putting the file. Anyways, thanks for solving this one!

Comment: Created a proper answer for this for posterity :).

Answer (score 0):

If downloading a zip is not working for you, a standard git method is to use `git archive`

```
git archive --format zip HEAD ..\repo.zip
```

This creates a zipped version of the latest tracked, committed files in the working tree in the `repo.zip` file. You must execute it in your local repo.

Comment: This suggestion would both be hard for a regular user to use to download the files (with no use of Git as I intended) and does not solve the problem. The newlines are still being removed.

Comment: @NotTheOP ok. I didn't realize that a solution without git.exe was required.

Comment: Well, I better include it in my original question. Thanks for your attempt, though!

Answer (score 0):

A possibly better option than `eol=crlf` which always converts LF to CRLF, is to use `-text` which never converts either way.

```
*.patch -text
```

(I haven't tested this yet.)